# FakeItEasy deep nested types faking

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

I have a complex object that I'm trying to fake.

```
interface IContext
{
    User User { get; }
}

A.CallTo(
    () => _fakeContext.User.Subscription.Attributes)
    .Returns(new List<Attribute>());
```

But I get the next exception:

`The current proxy generator can not intercept the specified method for the following reasons: - Non virtual methods can not be intercepted`

All nested types are properties, and they are simple anemic types with `get; set;` property modifiers. And when I look into the debugger they all are fakes.

**Is there any way to setup the last property** of the chain and avoid setuping all previous ones?

Comment: Are the property on `User` virtual? If so could you post the source code for `User`?

Comment: No. Neither User nor Subscription are virtual. It's code from the compiled assembly.

Comment: FakeItEasy cannot mock non virtual methods, so you have to resolve to build the object youself. Something like the answer below would do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your objects are anemic enough, you might want to give [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture) a go:

```
var fake = A.Fake<>();
var fixture = new Fixture();
// If it's possible [1], AutoFixture will generate entire object graph
var user = fixture.CreateAnonymous<User>();
// Since data will be random [2], you can overwrite properties as you like
user.User.Subscription.Attributes = new List<Attributes>();
A.CallTo(() => fake.User).Returns(user);
```

1. In order for it to work, your custom objects need to have public constructor and preferably avoid using interfaces (but that can be mitigated with *auto-mocking* extensions, like AutoFakeItEasy).
2. The `.Build` method provides fluent API to customize objects autogeneration, so the *randomness* can be controlled